# VM freezing during WinPE boot up

Tags: virtual-machines, windows-server-2012-r2, scvmm, windows-pe, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

Got SCVMM 2012 R2 up and running, created a single VM w/ dynamic memory (512MB-4096MB) and a 40GB dynamic disk. The host is configured for NIC Teaming using switch independent configuration.

I setup a legacy network adapter and boot up to WinPE. The version of the boot.wim is WinPE4, configured to launch sccm. I do not know if it has virtual nic and storage drivers, but I didn't have a problem when creating standard hyper-v VMs in the past (2012, non R2). It downloads the boot.wim, but freezes at the very end when (I'm assuming) it goes to unpack it.

[image]

That's a 100% progress bar, and it just sits there. I'm in the process of creating a fixed disk VM, but I doubt that will resolve the problem. Posting here in the mean time in case anyone else has come across this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears at the moment this was caused by the lack of HyperV drivers in the WinPE boot wim. The x64 version of the boot wim booted up fine. After looking at both in sccm, I noticed the 64 bit boot wim has an Intel emulated nic driver, while the 32 bit one does not.

[image]

Not sure where I'll be going from here.but this happened after upgrading our Windows Deployment Services (WDS) server to 2008r2.